# Easiest way to do form validations on button press in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a C# based WinForms application which has a lot of menus in it, each of which have multiple controls for user input .. All the forms have OK buttons which do processing on the inputs given by the user ..

I have to do validations on all these controls when the user presses the OK button for example .. To check if string entered is a number or not, is of a specific length or not, is present or not, etc ...

Is there any C# functionality available to do this, instead of me having to write full fledged  code for each OK button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to call `Validate` or `ValidateChildren` from the OK button click event handler.  You would then have a `Validating` event handler for each control to be validated.

See [this MSDN article on User Input Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can do validation using regular expression 
here is a link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: I think the user is aware of how to do validation. but his question is if it is possible to do this on a button click for multiple forms / controls

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to enter this kind of code in your form design then you could always make your own custom controls that are designed to work in a certain fashion.

So for instance, you could create a class that inherits from the TextBox class, and you can override the events of this control to do exactly what you want it to do.

Making your own controls that are designed to work exactly how you want them too. Doing things this way, you don't need to validate the input as much in your form design, as you set the behaviour of your control, and drop the control onto your form.

You will always have some validation on User input, but you can restrict it in the form events, it all depends on how customised you need these controls to be.

This kind of thing is good if you want the control to restrict certain keys, like a "Return key" in a RichTextBox, or you want to handle the clipboard content as its being pasted. You can do all this code in the class, rather than in your form.

Hope this helps.